# Magento Start Dataflow Profile with new CSV from Command Line

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I am running magento 1.6.2

I built a dataflow profile to import my customers/logins. All goes well there. I need to be able to run this every day, and I have seen some code out there to trigger dataflow profiles to run from the command line, but I can't figure out how to run the profile with a new CSV each time. Heck, I can't even find where it put the CSV that I uploaded! Any ideas where it might be? And does anybody know the best way to run a profile from the CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll answer my own question:

1. The directory where it puts files uploaded interactively is /tmp/magento/var/import/
2. Turns out, you don't need that information, because you don't want the interactive upload, you want the hard-coded path set in the "remote/local server" setting.
3. I got the command line import working by using the HO_Shellimport found here: https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_ShellImport. It's free and easy (no affiliation).

Comment: the import wizard is the slowest thing on the planet, if you have a few thousand records, but probably ok for a few hundred. I am working on a Direct MySQL method migrating from MyOb, as the import is just too slow...